HAProxy. How to change Authorization header
I have a working config of HAProxy that works in tcp mode.
I could capture the Authorization header that looks like 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0' (that means authorization type and username:password base64 encoded).
Sometimes after username:password present a 'new line' symbol and authorization header looks like 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0Cg=='
So I need to find and remove 'Cg==' from the end of authorization header.
How to do it?
frontend HAproxy
       mode tcp
       tcp-request content capture req.hdr(Authorization) len 128
backend server
        mode tcp
        server server1 172.16.1.1


I would add this two lines before the capture line, always.
tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
tcp-request content accept if HTTP

I would switch to mode http for such a capture as the req.hdr() is a http fetcher.
In http mode can you use something like the lines below.
# untested line
# just to get one possible solution
http-request set-var(txn.my_Authorization) req.hdr(Authorization),b64dec,cut_crlf,base64
http-request set-header Authorization %[var(txn.my_Authorization)]

All the above commands are documented in the excellent HAProxy Documentation
In the blog post Introduction to HAProxy ACLs are the HAProxy acl feature explained with some more examples

Thanks for your answer Aleksandar.
I'm using HAProxy in TCP mode and I can't switch it to mode http
Is there a solution for TCP mode? LUA script for example? Or

Well could be, I never used LUA for such a task.
